AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
My tensorflow graph neural network has a loss function looks like the code below. It calculates the loss based on the input key. Since gnn stores the key in bytes format, and I need to evaluate it to string for hashing the features. But it failed with eager execution is disabled.
#! /usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False) # numpy() works when eager is enabled

@tf.function
def loss_fn(d):
    return tf.reduce_mean(d['features'][d['key'][0].numpy().decode('utf-8')])

d = {'key': tf.constant(['A01', 'B01']),
     'features': {'A01': [0.1,0.2],
                  'B01': [0.3,0.4]}}
loss=loss_fn(d)

print(loss)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikehuang/programs/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    loss=loss_fn(d)
         ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mikehuang/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filezbap1vrc.py", line 12, in tf__loss_fn
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reduce_mean, (ag__.ld(d)['features'][ag__.converted_call(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(d)['key'][0].numpy, (), None, fscope).decode, ('utf-8',), None, fscope)],), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/home/mikehuang/programs/test.py", line 8, in loss_fn  *
        return tf.reduce_mean(d['features'][d['key'][0].numpy().decode('utf-8')])

    AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

How to access the feature based on input key?

.numpy() only works in eager mode.

is there any other method which could be used to evaluate the string as a key indexed into the feature dictionary?
